# Right column of table collapses when left column has content in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The following fiddle is driving me crazy. If I add content to the left column, the right column header loses its height in the amazing Internet Explorer browser. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/P3wBD/

HTML:

```
<table class="structure">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="left" rowSpan="2">
                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            </td>
            <td class="header" colSpan="2">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="content">
            </td>
            <td class="right">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Signika Negative";
}

.structure {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.structure > tbody > tr:first-child > td:last-child {
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.structure > tbody > tr > td {
    padding: 10px;
}

.structure > tbody > tr > td.left {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.structure > tbody > tr > td.header {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    text-align: right;
}

.structure > tbody > tr > td.content {
    border-right: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}

.structure > tbody > tr > td.right {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: There's a reason SO tells you to post code...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/P3wBD/

Comment: Yes, the problem really is that you're using a table for layout. I realize you said that "tableless [...] are harder to change" below, but they're actually not if done right. How did you try it? It can be as simple as defining one `<header>`, one `<nav>` and two `<div>`s, and that's much more elegant and flexible. Also, no name-calling pls.

Comment: Man, I know how to do it, and I will post the same layout fiddle in a few minutes for you. But you are also sounding pretentious. I have a team of c# coders that know the html and css basics, but they are not interface programmers. My company uses MVP strategy, and the product will change a lot in the next months, so I want to use tables and make it easy for the c# coders make small changes if needed without adding a interface programmer to the process (complexity in the team, one more resource that I don't need, etc).

Comment: Talking about tables, facebook uses it extensively because they are, most of the time, simpler to do, change and maintain. I know, I know, it is bad code, but whatever, code is here to make the business viable. I'm a mathematician and because of that I have a lot of aesthetics feelings about programming, but the reality is different, bad code, or the shitiest code in the world will work the same way and prove if a product idea is viable or not, so whatever is costless if fine for me. If the product is viable money will come in and I can hire a platoon of programmers to code everything again.

Comment: So when I ask why IE is doing something, and you come here to say that I'm doing it wrong, modern browser this, xy problem, you assume your political views about programming are right, you are assuming that you know my bussiness or product better than I do, you assume that what you know is better than what I know, or, using another word: you are being a pretentious douche. And like I said I love stackoverflow, but there are pretentious douches everywhere, and Im sick of it.

Comment: The same layout in tableless: http://jsfiddle.net/vBxAY/ that I dont want to use.

Comment: No, you're the one who's sounding pretentious here. We're offering you sound advice. I don't have political views on tables - I use them for layout sometimes. Sometimes they are convenient. This is one of the cases where they're not convenient. Using positioning is fine and will work in IE, and I don't see why you're so against it. That said, I don't care one way or another anymore. You've been exceedingly rude and unhelpful this whole time.

Answer (score 0):

Try not using tables for layout, they weren't designed for it and that's probably why they don't work.

Instead, try [absolute positioning](http://jsfiddle.net/P3wBD/1/) with `position:absolute`, `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` as needed.

Comment: This is not what I asked. I know everything about tableless, including the fact they are harder to change and harder to maintain and are completely useless for a administrative internal page.

Comment: Use `flexbox` layout then. The only problem with them is that they're only supported in newer browsers, but if it's internal admin stuff then it'll be fine.

Comment: What you're asking is an XY problem: You're asking how to make the wrong solution for the problem work right. It can't, it's wrong. I'm offering valid and suitable alternatives.

Comment: Which is it? An internal admin page, or a public one?

Comment: Because it is a internal administrative page it means that only modern browsers will access it? Sure...

Comment: Typically, an interal admin page is one that only you, or a limited number of people will access. Typically the ones who can access it are devleopers or at least technically knowledgable enough to upgrade their damn browsers.

Comment: @lolol - Please don't insult people who are trying to answer your questions. I've cleaned up the offending comments, but let's try to keep things professional here.